# Azure AD B2C Multiple Dynamic User Flows

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Does anybody know if and how can I use two (or more) user flows for user Sign Up from the same client application in Azure AD B2C? I want to be able to delegate to different signup flow based on the type of user that selected via the web application. One button "User Sign Up" and one button "Company Sign Up". How can I achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To support more than 1 Azure AD B2C user flow in a web app is pretty common. Keep in mind sign-in, sign-up, profile edit and more are all different user flows and are usually present in the same web app. In the same vein you can add any other flows that you want.

For implementation samples take a look to [Azure Active Directory B2C code samples.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples)